# get user and display info?

Tags: php, mysql

So i've got this input where i can put a username in and it'll use $_POST to get what i put in the input box however i'm struggling on how to get all the information from my database relating to this username and displaying it?

```
 <form action="ProcessPlayerSearch.php" method="POST">
     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" name="SearchUser" id="SearchUser" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-flat" type="button">Search</button>
                </span>
              </div>


     </h4>
            </form>
```

This is my ProcessPlayerSearch.php

```
function GetPlayerSearch(){
   global $database;
   $user = $_POST['Searchuser'];
   $q = "SELECT * FROM NEWPlayerInfo WHERE player=$user";
   $result = $database->query($q);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)){
      echo "User not found";
      return;
   }
   if($num_rows == 0){
      echo "User not found";
      return;
   }


   for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
      mysqli_data_seek($result, $i);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
      $uuid  = $row[0]; //UUID
      $player  = $row[1]; //player
      $kicks  = $row[2]; //kicks
      $bans  = $row[3]; //bans
      echo "$uuid<br>";
      echo "$player<br>";
      echo "$kicks<br>";
      echo "$bans<br>";
   }


}
```

and the error i get is

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

however i don't get why it would return a boolean? as i've entered a string into the input? Any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are displaying a single user data, Using for loop would be a little overhead. Now we return the array containing the user info from your function:

```
function GetPlayerSearch($user){
   global $database;
   $user = $_POST['Searchuser'];
   $q = "SELECT * FROM `NEWPlayerInfo` WHERE player='$user'";
   $result = $database->query($q);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   $res =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $userinfo =array();
   if($num_rows>1){
      $userinfo[] = $res;
   }else{
      $userinfo[] = array();
   }
   return $userinfo;
 }
```

Now search the user:

```
if(isset($_POST['SearchUser'])){   
    $user = isset($_POST['SearchUser'])? $_POST['SearchUser']:'';
    $player = GetPlayerSearch($user);
}
```

Display a single player data:

```
if(!empty($player)){ //you can also use array_filter()
      echo $player['UUID'].'<br>';
      echo $player['player'].'<br>';
      echo $player['kicks'].'<br>';
 }else{
      echo 'No user';
 }
```

Comment: If my answer does not help, I can delete always. Comment if you got a problem with my answer and show me your errors.